# How to improve results of Photoshop's magic wand tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm having an issue with the magic wand tool in Photoshop CC. When I select the black part of the image below and click backspace to remove everything inside the selection, lines on the outside of the selection remain.

Before:

[image: Black part selected with magic wand]

After:

[image: Lines remain]

How can you get rid of those lines without manually erasing them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try increasing your magic wand's tolerance so it selects more dark greys as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the Magic Wand isn't quite picking up all the black.

To fix this, after making your selection with the Magic Wand tool, choose Select > Modify > Expand... A dialog box will open allowing you to set the pixel amount you want to expand your selection. 1px or 2px should do the trick (more than that and you'll start getting some of the white/red around the black area).

[image]
[image]

Comment: That worked prefectly! Didn't know that control existed!

Comment: You can also use the [Refine Edge](http://i.imgur.com/8RB1jBZ.png) window.  It gives you way more control over your selections. @DavidCorbin